# How to draw x axis in a canvas using Tcl/Tk

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I wanted to plot an x-axis with respect to time ,for which i have a list which contains time values. Is it possible to display it in a tk canvas??

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Is it the answer on your question?

Comment: If you have Wish, there are demos for graphs.

Answer (score 0):

You can [easily plot a graph in a Tk canvas](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1123). You've just got to work out what points you really want to plot (i.e., assemble both the X and Y values). Adapted from the code on that page:

```
set width 100
set height 100
pack [canvas .c -width $width -height $height]

# Assuming you've got a list of points in $data
set count 0
foreach yValue $data {
    lappend coords \
            [expr {$width * $count/double([llength $data])}] \
            [expr {$height - $yValue}]
    incr count
}
.c create line $coords
```

Scaling the coordinates is just a matter of plugging the right code into the expressions.

More complex graphing capabilities are supported by the [plotchart](http://wiki.tcl.tk/11265) package. It's quite [a lot more complex](http://core.tcl.tk/tklib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tklib/files/modules/plotchart/plotchart.html) to start with, but is built on the same foundations.