# Adjust Y values before plotting the graph Tcl / Tk

Tags: linux, plot, graph, tcl, tk-toolkit

I made a code to produce a graph based on a column of values in a text file, however these values seem too small when plotted on to the graph, as the average data inside the text files looks like this :

```
0.00
4.42
1.10
0.47
0.21
0.51
0.28
0.21
0.01
0.00
```

How do i alter my code so that i can increase the values by a standard amount before the code plots the graph?

here is my code:

```
package require Tk

set width 300
set height 100
set openFile [open "/fileDirectory/file.txt"]
set records [read $openFile]
set data $records

canvas .c -width $width -height $height

text .t
.t insert end $records

pack .c 
pack .t

set count 0 

foreach yValue $data {
  lappend coords \
  [expr {$width * $count/double([llength $data])}] \
  [expr {$height - $yValue}]
  incr count
}
.c create line $coords
```

*Code to generate the graph is referenced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863549/how-to-draw-x-axis-in-a-canvas-using-tcl-tk)

Any alternative solution to better display the Y values onto the canvas without the need to change the original value would help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further research into the Tcl/Tk environment, i found out about Gnuplot and this seems to solve my problem to an extent. Gnuplot adjusts it's coordinates automatically to the data provided.

Answer (score 0):

The task of showing a picture  on a device needs several coordinations systems and several transformations:

1) first you have to map the picture in World Coordinates to the normalized device coordinates (viewport). This is the so called Window / Viewport transformation.

The formula is:
Xv = [(Xvmax - Xvmin)/(Xwmax - Xwmin)] * (Xw - Xwmin) + Xvmin 
= Sx * (Xw - Xwmin) + Xvmin = Sx * Xw + Cx

where Sx = (Xvmax - Xvmin)/(Xwmax - Xwmin) 
Cx = Sx * (- Xwmin) + Xvmin

Similarly for Y

Yv = [(Yvmax - Yvmin) / (Ywmax - Ywmin)] * (Yw - Ywmin) + Yvmin 
= Sy * (Yw - Ywmin) + Yvmin = Sy * Yw + Cy 
(taken from the reference below)

2) the second step is the transformation to the physical device (Screen , Printer ....)
The canvas widget takes care of that. Zooming in or out is possible with the scale method of the canvas.

The answer is that you should perform the Window-Viewport transformation first.

-- joachim
https://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/viewing/view2d/pwint.htm